# Using functions with raw inputs

Tags: python, function

I was experimenting with what I have learned so far and I wanted to create something that is interactive, using `raw_input()`.

What I wanted to do was creating a function that will create a conversation which will go different directions based on input. However, I was unable to figure out how to make a function accept the `raw_input` as its argument.

Here is the code that I've written;

```
drink = raw_input("Coffee or Tea?")

def drinktype(drink):
    if drink == "Coffee":
    #I WANT TO INSERT A CODE HERE THAT WILL CALL THE FUNCTION coffee(x)
    elif drink == "Tea":
        print "Here is your tea."
    else:
        print "Sorry."

x = raw_input("Americano or Latte?")

def coffee(x):
    if x == "Americano":
        return "Here it is."    
    elif x == "Latte":
        return "Here is your latte."
    else:
        return "We do not have that, sorry."
```

Comment: As is, this code does not work. Please make sure that you are at least abiding by Python's syntax and also ensure you are properly indented. Indentation is important in Python.

Comment: You don't seem to ever _call_ your functions.

Comment: I changed indentations, thanks for reminding but I was careless while pasting the code here, sorry. How do I call the functions?

Comment: @sonooob - Along with indentation, please restructure your code. Define all functions first then main function. Run it and please paste output/error. . Cheers !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request for americano or latte is something you only need to do if coffee is requested; it is irrelevant if the user requests tea. Once that is moved under the Coffee case, you can simply pass the returned value to your call to `coffee()`. The return value also needs to be printed.

```
def drinktype(drink):
    if drink == "Coffee":
        kind = raw_input("Americano or Latte?")
        print coffee(kind)
    elif drink == "Tea":
        print "Here is your tea."
    else:
        print "Sorry."

def coffee(x)
    if x == "Americano":
        return "Here it is."    
    elif x == "Latte":
        return "Here is your latte."
    else:
        return "We do not have that, sorry."

drink = raw_input("Coffee or Tea?")
drinktype(drink)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
drink = raw_input("Coffee or Tea?")

def drinktype(drink):
    if drink == "Coffee":
        usercoffeetype = raw_input("What type of coffee do you drink?")
        coffee(usercoffeetype)
    elif drink == "Tea":
        print "Here is your tea."
    else:
        print "Sorry."

x = raw_input("Americano or Latte?")

def coffee(x)
    if x == "Americano":
        return "Here it is."    
    elif x == "Latte":
        return "Here is your latte."
    else:
        return "We do not have that, sorry."
```

Also just a note - using variable names like "x" is generally not a good idea. It'd be better if your variable name actually described what it holds, like this:

```
def coffee(coffeechoice)
    if coffeechoice == "Americano":
        return "Here it is."    
    elif coffeechoice == "Latte":
        return "Here is your latte."
    else:
        return "We do not have that, sorry."
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to get something like the following

```
def coffee():   
    x = raw_input("Americano or Latte?")
    if x == "Americano":
        return "Here it is."    
    elif x == "Latte":
        return "Here is your latte."
    else:
        return "We do not have that, sorry."

def drinktype(drink):
    if drink == "Coffee":
        print coffee()
    elif drink == "Tea":
        print "Here is your tea."
    else:
        print "Sorry."


drink = raw_input("Coffee or Tea?")

drinktype(drink)
```

Please note that
1. correct indentation is crucial for you code to work
2. after defining a function drinktype(), you need to actually call it to let it run. (the last line is calling the function)

Comment: oh, I see now. Thank you.